# Log4j2 - How to configure JDBC Appender?

Tags: java, logging, jdbc, log4j, log4j2

Is it possible to configure JDBC appender in log4j v2?

---

There was no problem to do it in log4j v1.2.9, but i didn't find any information in log4j2 documentation about this. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Do you mean, using log4jdbc with log4j 2? If you do, I answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15731870/1768736

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of beta4 (and soon to be released beta5) there is no JDBC appender.

I suggest you ask for this feature on the mailing list or by filing a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2) with your feature request.

---

UPDATE: beta7 (June 2013) added support for JDBC, JPA, and NoSQL database Appenders.