# How to configure log4j2.xml for log4jdbc?

Tags: java, xml, logging, jdbc, log4j2

Does anyone know how to configure the log4j2.xml file to use log4jdbc? I have been searching for several hours and I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

log4jdbc relies on [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/). There is to date no proper connector between SLF4J and Log4j 2.

If you want, you can instead use [log4jdbc-log4j2](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/), which addresses exactly this need of getting log4j2 to work with log4jdbc.

Comment: There is now both a bridge [ http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html ] and an adapter http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html ]. Don't use them both together or you'll find a race condition.

Comment: Also, what a monstrosity is log4jdbc-log4j2. Totally unnecessary given the Marker functionality of Log4j2! Or, would someone please explain its utility?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment, as log4jdbc-log4j2 makes use of the Marker functionality (see "List of all available Markers"). Its utility is exactly the same than log4jdbc, except it allows to use Log4j2.

Answer (score 1):

As of beta5, Log4j 2.0 does not offer a JDBC Appender. However, the team is working on one and it is likely that a subsequent release will contain one.

Which also means: if you have any feature requests, ideas or comments, now would be a good time to let the team know!

The dev mailing list, user mailing list or Jira issue tracker are all fine places to get your voice heard.

---

Update:
As of beta 7, Log4j2 offers JDBC, JPA, and NoSQL database appenders.

Comment: Actually I was excited about this announcement in the first place, then I realize: it will still depend on the JDBC driver used whether `PreparedStatement` queries are logged with real parameter values, rather than placeholders. I guess the JDBC Appender will not have the capability to intercept setter calls, am I correct? In that case, this answer seems irrelevant.

Comment: Djebel, i'm not sure what you have in mind. If you have a feature request can I suggest you direct it to the log4j team (Jira, mailing list, anything is fine)? The feature might already exist and may just need better documentation, or it could be added.

Comment: Well, I prefer not too, as I think it is not doable by a JDBC Appender, so I was asking you just to be sure. I mean, logging `PreparedStatement` with real parameter values, for instance `select * from user where userId = 1` rather than `...where userId = ?`. I think the JDBC Appender will rely on the `PreparedStatement.getString()` method, and it depends on the implementation of the JDBC library whether this method returns real parameter values.